# How can a representation of a literal be safely evaluated, assuming unicode_literals?

Tags: python, unicode, eval, python-2.x, literals

In Python 2, I would like to evaluate a string that contains the representation of a literal.  I would like to do this safely, so I don't want to use `eval()`—instead I've become accustomed to using `ast.literal_eval()` for this kind of task.

However, I also want to evaluate under the assumption that string literals in plain quotes denote `unicode` objects—i.e. the kind of forward-compatible behavior you get with `from __future__ import unicode_literals`.  In the example below, `eval()` seems to respect this preference, but `ast.literal_eval()` seems not to.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function

import ast

raw = r"""   'hello'    """

value = eval(raw.strip())
print(repr(value))
# Prints:
# u'hello'

value = ast.literal_eval(raw.strip())
print(repr(value))
# Prints:
# 'hello'
```

Note that I'm looking for a general-purpose `literal_eval` replacement—I don't know in advance that the output is necessarily a string object.  I want to be able to assume that `raw` is the representation of an arbitrary Python literal, which may be a string, or may contain one or more strings, or not.

Is there a way of getting the best of both worlds:  a function that both securely evaluates representations of arbitrary Python literals *and* respects the `unicode_literals` preference?

Comment: @wim I submitted it, but the response was that it's not a bug if a function merely fails to do what we *think* the user *might* expect. Rather, a bug would be something that, for example, directly goes against the documentation. In this case the official doc for both `literal_eval` and `unicode_literals` seems too brief to generate specific expectations about this behavior.   So this would be a new feature (against policy for Python 2.7) and more importantly would potentially break backward compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither `ast.literal_eval` nor `ast.parse` offer the option to set compiler flags. You can pass the appropriate flags to `compile` to parse the string with `unicode_literals` activated, then run `ast.literal_eval` on the resulting node:

```
import ast

# Not a future statement. This imports the __future__ module, and has no special
# effects beyond that.
import __future__

unparsed = '"blah"'
parsed = compile(unparsed,
                 '<string>',
                 'eval',
                 ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST | __future__.unicode_literals.compiler_flag)
value = ast.literal_eval(parsed)
```

Comment: @jez: I happen to have already edited the code to work for `'3'` while you were writing that comment.

Comment: On wim's answer you wrote "I'm not quite sure whether it'd be possible to write an input that's safe when parsed with unicode_literals off, but unsafe with unicode_literals on".   To the best of my understanding, your own solution should be immune to this (potential) problem, even if such an input were to exist—is that correct?

Comment: Ok then that’s my reason for choosing this answer

Comment: May be worth noting that `import __future__` and `| __future__.unicode_literals.compiler_flag` are redundant if `compile` is being called in the same file as the initial `from __future__ import unicode_literals` statement, because `compile` inherits its caller's flags by default.

Answer (score 4):

An interesting question. I'm not sure if there is any solution for `ast.literal_eval`, here, but I offer a cheap/safe workaround:

```
def my_literal_eval(s):
    ast.literal_eval(s)
    return eval(s)
```

Comment: Isn't that as unsafe as using `eval()` by itself?

Comment: @alexis: Not quite, because `ast.literal_eval` will throw an exception on (most?) unsafe input before it reaches `eval`. I'm not quite sure whether it'd be possible to write an input that's safe when parsed with `unicode_literals` off, but unsafe with `unicode_literals` on, though.

Comment: @alexis no, it's not evaluating the output of the previous `literal_eval`. It's evaluating the input again.   This solution is sneaky and ingenious.  I'm wondering if there's a valid unicode literal representation that will trip up `ast.literal_eval`  though...?

Answer (score 1):

What makes codes potentially insecure are references to names and/or attributes. You can subclass `ast.NodeVisitor` to ensure that there are no such references in a given piece of code before you `eval` it:

```
import ast
from textwrap import dedent

class Validate(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Name(self, node):
        raise ValueError("Reference to name '%s' found in expression" % node.id)
    def visit_Attribute(self, node):
        raise ValueError("Reference to attribute '%s' found in expression" % node.attr)

Validate().visit(ast.parse(dedent(raw), '<inline>', 'eval'))
eval(raw)
```

Comment: [You don't need Name nodes to get arbitrary code execution.](https://ideone.com/EQjyOq)

Comment: Looks like `EnsureNoNames().visit()` is being used as a "screening" step to detect whether the subsequent `eval(raw)` will be safe.  Is there any advantage to using a screening function other than `ast.literal_eval()` itself (wim's solution)?      user2357112's ingenious counterexample `raw = '''().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()[-1].format.__globals__['__builtins__']['eval'](
    '__import__("os").system("echo Arbitrary code executed.")')'''` shows that this particular screening function has security holes.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks. I've updated my answer to account for the use of attributes then.

Comment: @jez No there isn't any meaningful advantage to wim's answer that I can think of (other than a friendlier error message). This was just an attempt at an alternative solution for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @blhsing Thanks for clarifying.  This answer and user2357112's have together taught me a lot I didn't know about `ast`

Comment: While I can't currently think of any way to get arbitrary code execution with both Name and Attribute nodes forbidden, a blacklist approach is still inherently riskier than the whitelist approach taken by `ast.literal_eval`. A whitelist makes it a lot easier than a blacklist to go through every allowed operation and verify that it's safe, especially as the language evolves and new syntax is added. (Python 2 may not be evolving at this point, but any Python 2 code has to be written with Python 3 migration in mind.)